# Can I create a Java Swing container without Administrator privileges from a program run as Administrator?

Tags: java, windows, administrator

I have an Administrative DOS window from which I launch a Java application.  The Java application therefore runs as Administrator.  The Java application launches a JPanel which acts as if it was run as Administrator.  I have reason to want to avoid this--is there a way to demote the JPanel so that it behaves as if it wasn't run as Administrator?

Comment: I can't imagine it's straightforward. If this is Windows, can't you just use `runas` or something like that, to run the whole program as the user you want?

Comment: With "behaves" do you mean "is running with privileges" right? Is the JPanel part of the same process or executed as separate application?

Comment: Would checking if you were administer, if so then close; be acceptable behavior?